# Setting up Grid Engine

Tags: 16.04

As I'm working on setting up grid engine... I'm stuck with an issue. As I check what are the running deamons using the following command.... The result I get is (as listed):

```
ps aux | grep sge


sgeadmin  1069  0.0  0.0  68896  3372 ?        Sl   10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/gridengine/sge_execd
sayantan  9545  0.0  0.0  21292   968 pts/5    S+   10:56   0:00 grep --color=auto sge
```

Now, if I log into root and use the following commands:
(i.e. after sudo su)

```
sge_qmaster
```

This doesn't give any output.

But then, as I try to start the exec:

```
sge_execd
```

The error I get is:

```
error: communication error for "localhost/execd/1" running on port 6445: "can't bind socket"
error: commlib error: can't bind socket (no additional information available)
```

I'm stuck for quite some time now. Request some help.

Comment: How did you install gridengine? `apt-get install gridengine...` or from 3rdparty?

Comment: Hey... Thanks.. I did use apt-get... and installed all the gridengine related stuffs too:  apt-get install gridengine-master gridengine-exec gridengine-common gridengine-qmon gridengine-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get from `sge_execd` points to that the `sge_execd` process is running already and has allocated port `6445` already and therefore a second instance cannot use the port again.

Since `sge_execd` and `sge_qmaster` are services, they shouldn't be started directly on the commandline but rather through the init-scripts that are shipped with the packages. Additionally, the init-scripts will pick up some SGE related environment variables to make the services work correctly.
From Ubuntu 16.04 and onwards, `systemd` is normally used to manage startup scripts. In case of the `gridengine` scripts, the `systemd` way seems not to work. You should enable the SGE parts to start automatically on boot as follows.

```
$ sudo update-rc.d gridengine-master enable
$ sudo update-rc.d gridengine-exec enable
```

---

To start the services correctly for now, you could first stop the instances and the start them through `systemd`.

```
$ sudo killall sge_qmaster
$ sudo killall sge_execd
```

Then check if the processes went away.

```
$ sudo ps aux | grep sge | grep -v grep
```

After that try to start the services.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart gridengine-master.service
$ sudo systemctl restart gridengine-exec.service
```

Comment: By the time you commented, I did uninstall all the stuffs.... Now, once I try systemctl enable, I get the following:  gridengine-exec.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gridengine-exec

Comment: Hence, I'm using systemctl restart/start and then I see that gridengine-master doesnt't start...but the exec starts

Comment: If the master does not start, you should look into `/var/spool/gridengine/qmaster/messages` for errors preventing the master to start.

Comment: Hey Thomas... Thanks a lot.... Worst thing is there's no gridengine folder in spool

Comment: Can I again try something like this for a fresh install, without any reference, whatsoever, to the previous install: sudo aptitude remove gridegnine-* --purge... And then reinstall all?

Comment: It seems clean uninstall isn't happening.... So, while I'm reinstalling its just asking for Postfix config (which I'm skipping with no config)

Comment: I did a clean uninstall, purging and then updating index of packages. Thereafter, I reinstalled the packages. Now it's working fine...! Thanks a lot Thomas